Dockerfile run error. Always having an error "Topology is closed"
I have this error about "Topology is closed" something which unable to connect to mongodb with also with this error MongooseServerSelectionError. Kindly check the error logs below.
I tried many configs from other sources but no luck. Hope someone already know/able to fix this.
Error: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:27017/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:225
    drainWaitQueue(this[kWaitQueue], new error_1.MongoTopologyClosedError());
MongoTopologyClosedError: Topology is closed
    at Topology.close (/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:225:42)
    at Topology._connect (/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:211:18)
    at async Topology.connect (/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:158:13)
    at async topologyConnect (/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:204:17)
    at async MongoClient._connect (/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:217:13)
    at async MongoClient.connect (/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:142:13)
    at async NativeConnection.createClient (/home/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:314:3)
    at async NativeConnection.openUri (/home/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:846:5) {
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v19.9.0

I tried a lot configurations on these link but no luck.
MongoDB on with Docker "failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect "
MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
My dockerfile
FROM node:19-alpine
ENV MONGO_DB_USERNAME=admin \
    MONGO_DB_PWD=password

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

COPY . /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
CMD ["node", "./dist/index.js"]

My mongodb connection
import mongoose from "mongoose";
//localhost ~~ 127.0.0.1 ~~ 0.0.0.0 won't work
// tried this "mongodb" or "mongo-express" from docker-compose file still not working
export const mongooDbConnect = () => {
  mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://admin:password@0.0.0.0:27017", { 
      dbName: "car_be",
    })
    .then(() =>
      console.log(
        "****************\n\n Connected to the MONGODB database \n\n****************"
      )
    )
    .catch((err) => console.log(`Error: ${err}`));

  return mongoose;
};

My docker-compose file
version: "3"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always 
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local

PS. I'm able to run fully functional only in local. only the docker image not able to connect.


*note - I'm able to run my app and connected using npm run start with localhost:8080 mondo-express built & run by docker.

I just solved this issue by changing the 0.0.0.0 / 127.0.0.1 / localhost to the IP address given from the docker host. You can locate it from here
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc4\host.txt


